# SVG: Insert custom element into text

Tags: svg

I have an SVG image where I've defined a custom symbol that I want to use (a `<path>` element with an `id`), and I want to insert it into some text in a `<text>` or `<tspan>` element.

I've tried using `<glyph>` and similar tags like it but they're all deprecated. Putting it as a `<g>` inside the `<tspan>` didn't work either as it simply wouldn't show anything, nor did putting it inside the enveloping `<text>` element. Defining a class in the style and adding `::after` also didn't help.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Permited content inside a <tspan>: <a>, <animate>, <set>, <tspan> and descriptive elements (<desc>, <metadata>, <title>) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan#usage_notes

Comment: You need to convert your icon to a font (e.g using a free service like [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) or fontello)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/typography/opentype/spec/svg